# Как сделать правильную проверку заполненности строки?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо проверить заполненность полей и запретить доступ к слайдеру, если поля заполнены то доступ к следующему этапу открыт.
У меня не работает проверка, вроде строка пустая и input.value == ''. Но безрезультатно. В чем может крыться проблема?

```
<style>

.check {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.check li.active {
display: block;
}
.check li {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 600px;
    background: #fafafa;
    display: none;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
</style>
<form action="" class="form-margin-top">
    <ul class="check">
        <li class="mySlides active">
            <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-text">
                        <p>Ваш вопрос?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-text text-align">
                        <p>Другой вопрос? <span>*</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="special">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-text">
                        <p>Еще один вопрос <span>*</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="special">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mySlides">
            <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-text">
                        <p>Ваш вопрос?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-text text-align">
                        <p>Другой вопрос? <span>*</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="special">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-text">
                        <p>Еще один вопрос <span>*</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="special">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mySlides">
            <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-text">
                        <p>Ваш вопрос?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-text text-align">
                        <p>Другой вопрос? <span>*</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="special">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-text">
                        <p>Еще один вопрос <span>*</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="special">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <button type="button" class="send-btn btn_left">Prev</button type="button">
        <button type="button" class="send-btn btn_right">Next</button>
    </ul>
</form>

<script>
    var btn_prev = document.querySelector('.btn_left');
    var btn_next = document.querySelector('.btn_right');
    var slide = document.querySelectorAll('.check .mySlides');
    var i = 0;
    var input = document.querySelector('.special');

    if(input.value == ''){

        document.querySelectorAll('.form-text p span').textContent = 'Заполните стороку';

    }else{

        btn_next.onclick = function(){
            slide[i].classList.remove('active');
            i++;
            if(i > slide.length -1){
                i = 0;
            }
            slide[i].classList.add('active');
        }

        btn_prev.onclick = function(){
            slide[i].classList.remove('active');
            i--;
            if(i < 0){
                i = slide.length -1;
            }
            slide[i].classList.add('active');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: В вашем примере if(input.value == ''){} ета часть кода всегда будет возвращать true и условия выполнитса.Так как мы javascript код инициализируем только 1 раз, тогда вам надо повесить обработчик событий на input и если изминилось состояния тогда уже делать след. действия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('listen');

input.onblur = function() {
  if (input.value === '') { 
    input.classList.add('red');
  }
};
```

```css
.red{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input id="listen" />
```

Вам нужно добавить обработчик событий на input,если его состояния не изменилось тогда делать то что вам уже надо!Не используйте два равно, почти всегда используйте === , в дальнейшем это поможет вам избежать ошибок!
https://habr.com/ru/post/138272/

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли